# Cloth sim problem levitating pillows

Tags: modeling, rendering

I have a massive problem with cloth sim. I'm trying to recreate sofa from reference photo (so far so bad) and when I'm trying to "drop" cushion on a sofa (both back side and seats are set to be collision). Unfortunatly everytime no matter how i tweak settings my pillows levitate in the air... What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/dKHEelp.jpg forget to add a photo...

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the collision minimum distance;

[image]